# Add Run Jasmine Tests Build Step to Dotnet Core Project

Tags: jasmine, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

What are the proper steps to run jasmine for dotnet core project in Visual Studio Team Services CI (was Visual Studio Online)?

Comment: How do you run it locally? You can provide the detail steps.

Comment: Do you run glup task with Jasmine through gulpfile.js file? If so, add grunt task to your build definition to run that grunt task. With grunt task you also could configure Code Coverage with Jasmine test framework.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I was very new to js, when I asked this question. I think I will just write a repo as an answer to this question. Sorry for late response.